# Did I use pronoun correctly in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

In the following sentence, does "**these**" correctly refer to three types of penalties that I have already mentioned in the last sentence? Is it clear that I am telling that based on the crime, judge can use one of these options?

> There is a wide range of prison sentences such as life, fixed-term,
> and suspended imprisonment. Judiciary can opt for one of **these**, based
> on the severity of the crime that an offender has committed.

Comment: Yes, it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is clear that "these" refers to "a wide range of prison sentences". However, "judiciary" is not properly used here. It should be "the judge" or "the court".  "Judiciary" means the whole institution or the government branch, not a single court.

Comment: Thanks. but I do not speak about a specific judge or court. Can I use `a judge` or `judges`?

Comment: @a.toraby Yes, "A Judge" or "judges" could be used. So could "A court". However, "The judge" would mean "The judge in the case being considered". and would not narrow the meaning.